# Understanding Haskell profiler output - what is ==_a3JO

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I am writing some optimization application in Haskell and I just ran it through profiler. I can see many functions and a strange symbol "==_a3JO" (sometimes different numbers and leters). What does it stand for?

Sample output:

```
      maxDistanceRaw Igc                                                  360      471912   5.2    5.7    19.8   20.3
       distance      Igc                                                  364    30143010   1.3    1.0    14.6   14.6
        distanceRad  Igc                                                  365    30143010  10.4    8.8    13.3   13.6
         ==_a3JO     Igc                                                  366    30143010   2.9    4.9     2.9    4.9
     ==_a3JO         Igc                                                  350   233432454  35.3   36.9    35.3   36.9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `distanceRad` have an `Eq` instance as an argument? I've only used the profiler a few times, but it looks like it's an instance implementation of `(==)` that has been name-mangled to be unique.

(Posting the code might help.)

Comment: Should have occured to me :) Yes, it is - and I am spending 60% of time comparing things. The profile turned out to be very useful indeed...

Comment: It has for me too. I've compared two algorithms that had the same complexity bound and the actual performance was exactly backward from what I predicted. Profiling in a lazy language is super important.